# database does not connect if i use require once in another PHP page

Tags: php

i have to use every time database connection in each page of php to make it work. Require once is not working in cpanel.

i tried required once and__DIR__ 'dbconnection.php' but not successful. I have to write everytime database connection code in each page.

Comment: "not successful" means what exactly? Are you getting a specific error? Have you even checked the PHP error log file for information about the problem? Have you debugged to see if `__DIR__ 'dbconnection.php'` returns the path you expected it to?? We can't help you without proper information including all relevant code and debug info, in the form of a [mre] of the issue. Currently you're basically asking us to guess, which isn't very productive. We can't see your environment to check these basic things - that's your job. See also [ask]. You can [edit] the question when you have more info. Thanks

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/khjargficdhx/public_html/file-entry.biharscb.co.indbConnection.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in /home/khjargficdhx

Comment: Well that seems pretty obvious doesn't it. Have you looked closely at that path string? What do you notice - especially about the filename?

Comment: As @ADyson mention your questions details are too vague. But should understand that PHP is a execution script and database needs to be open on each execution. Once the execution is over the database is closed. So primordial scripts always must include a configuration process where you can load a previous session, open databases, load libraries and classes or an autoloader function.

Comment: @CarlosH. the OP understands that already. That's exactly what they were trying to do. But they wanted to avoid repeating all that code by including the DB connection code stored once in a single file into other files. If you look at the error message provided in the comments it becomes clear that the only problem is a simple typo.

Comment: Yes I noticed the extra comments after I posted mine. The problem looks like is missing the `/` in between the require path. And verification that the script exists on that path.